# Android - Google Sign In Error - There is no linked app associated with this client ID

Tags: google-play, android

Здравствуйте!
Пишу игрушку под андройд и хочу прикрутить к ней таблицу рекордов от гугла, вроде все сделал по инструкции, но не взлетает.
Вызываю активити.

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LeaderBoardActivity.class));
```

Код активити

```
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;
```

public class LeaderBoardActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedClients(BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_GAMES);

```
    // obtain the underlying GameHelper (this must be done
    // AFTER setRequestedClients)
    //GameHelper helper = getGameHelper();

    // add APIs and/or scopes to the builder:
    //GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = helper.createApiClientBuilder();
    //builder.addApi(YOUR_ADDITIONAL_API_HERE);
    //builder.addScope(YOUR_CUSTOM_SCOPE_HERE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.leader_board_layout);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    // Sign in has failed. So show the user the sign-in button.
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    // show sign-out button, hide the sign-in button
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.leaderboard_test), 1337);

    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.leaderboard_test)), 1);

    // (your code here: update UI, enable functionality that depends on sign in, etc)
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
        // start the asynchronous sign in flow
        beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
    }
    else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
        // sign out.
        signOut();

        // show sign-in button, hide the sign-out button
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

}

В манифесте

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                   android:value="@string/app_id" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
```

В strings

```
    <string name="app_id">1091725568090</string>
<string name="leaderboard_test">CgkI2tCo_-IfEAIQDQ</string>
```

Подключен GameBaseUtils и сервисы гугла как библиотеки.

При попытке подключения ругается так

```
E/SignInIntentService﹕ There is no linked app associated with this client ID.
...
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ ****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ ****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ ****     a test account.
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ ****
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** To help you debug, here is the information about this app
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** Package name         : com.xxx.xxx
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** Cert SHA1 fingerprint: 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** App ID from          : 1234567890
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ ****
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** Check that the above information matches your setup in
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** Developer Console. Also, check that you're logging in with the
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** right account (it should be listed in the Testers section if
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** your project is not yet published).
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ ****
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ **** For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:
10-13 19:27:37.110    6658-6658/com.moitalant.Hundred W/GameHelper﹕ ****   [url]http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting[/url]
```

Настройки в гугл плей следующие:

- Добавлено и опубликовано приложение
- Привязаны достижения к нему и так же опубликованы
- Добавлены сертификаты и    привязаны
     к пакету

Вроде на этом все. Может кто подскажет где ошибка или куда копать?

Comment: А в консоли добавили https://console.developers.google.com?

Comment: >Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match

Сертификат с консоли скопировали в свою аппу?

Comment: Да, добавил два ключа SHA1 (дебаг и релизный), добавил апи Google Play App State, Google Play Game Management, Google Play Game Services, Google+ API. добавил CLIENT ID и API KEY. в консоли пишет 19 запросов 19 ошибок а логи не показывает - зависает страница

Comment: Эмм...какой именно сертификат? как он выглядит? скопировал id приложения